# Java reg pattern capturing multiple sets

Tags: java, regex

I have a String value of `X-Y-Z-A`

From the following pattern `([a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z])`, I was able to capture the set `X-Y` and `Z-A`. But this is not sufficient.

**Q:** Is it possible to construct a regular expression that captures set `X-Y`, `Y-Z` and `Z-A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=(\w-\w))
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/12

Comment: `\w` includes `0-9`, `_` also.

Comment: And just changing `[a-zA-Z]` to `\w` doesn't mean your regex wasn't borrowed from mine below.

Comment: @Tendious: You also need to understand this important difference between `\w` and `[A-Za-z]`. `\w` means `[A-Za-z0-9_]` whereas as per your question you want to capture `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @anubhava i didnt check your ans. was typing my own and have also posted my link

Comment: You can look at the timestamps of both answers. Once you realize you're too late in answering a problem and your answer is already there then simply delete your answer to avoid redundant answers on a question.

Comment: @anubhava that can be left to OP to decide i guess.

Comment: Not really, that is the practice followed on SO. Person posting duplicate answer is the one who deletes it. OP in cases like this can be very new and may not understand the ethical practices followed here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, instead of matching text use positive lookahead regex:

```
(?=([a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z]))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oP1tS3/1)

For your input `"X-Y-Z-A"` it gives these 3 matches:

1. `"X-Y"`
2. `"Y-Z"`
3. `"Z-A"`

Answer (score 1):

To capture the overlapping characters, you need to include the capturing group inside a lookbehind or lookahead.

```
(?<=([A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z]))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/11)